# separated numbers three to three?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can when that typed numbers in input:text, separated them three to three and between them puting this:","?
**normal number formatting**

Example: typed this number in input: `45656839`
result (live - online) in same input: `45,656,839`
**i not want use of plugin.**

With respect

Comment: So us what you've attempted to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ucf/)

This should do it for you.

```
<input type="text" class="numeric" />
```

```
$("input:text.numeric").keyup(function(){
    $val = $(this).val();
    $(this).val($val.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(","))
});
```

#### EDIT

For normal number formatting, the code is a little different.  There's probably a some good regex out there for this but my first thought was to reverse the string and apply the same technique.  Then you reverse the string again and you have it

```
$("input:text.numeric").keyup(function(){
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

#### EDIT 2

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ucf/1/)

And for future reference if anyone wants to implement this with decimal places (yeah I got carried away :P) ...

```
$("input:text.numeric").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which > 40 || e.which == 8) {
        var num = $(this).val().match(/[0-9,]*/g)[0];
        var decimalNum = $(this).val().match(/[.][0-9]*/) || "";
        if(num) {
            var wholeNum = num.match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
            var resultNum = wholeNum + decimalNum;
            $(this).val(resultNum);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).val(num);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joseph - thanks. for this: 45,165,874 or 4,521,243 how is it?(normal number formatting)

Comment: @NayantharaJudila ah! normal number formatting... that's different, but not impossible. I'll post a revision.

Answer (score 2):

I think that masked input plugin could be a good solution. You can read more here: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: So you want to reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: I'd highly recommend the usage of a plugin instead of trying to invent this yourself.

Comment: I would highly recommend the usage of jQuery instead of a plugin... you have much more control over it and in this case it's super easy.

Comment: Wheel who hurts you it is better not to use of it. Size the plugin is much more of write code by yourself.

Comment: Just to throw this in there: A plugin is not always the solution. Sometimes it can be better to write it from scratch, especially if it's not really complicated. The benefits include easier to customize, leaner code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
function thousandSeparator(n,sep) {
    var sRegExp = new RegExp('(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})'),
    sValue=n+'';

    if (sep === undefined) {sep=',';}
    while(sRegExp.test(sValue)) {
        sValue = sValue.replace(sRegExp, '$1'+sep+'$2');
    }
    return sValue;
}
```

From: http://webdesign.onyou.ch/2010/08/04/javascript-inserting-thousand-separators/

Comment: For the example in the question, this outputs "4,565,683,985", which is not how the OP wants it.

Comment: Reverse, then call, then reverse :P Sorry, you're totally right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this (untested, should work):

```
$(':text').blur(function(){
  var $this = $(this), val = $this.val(), newVal = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    newVal += val.charAt(i)
    if (!((i + 1) % 3))
      newVal += ','
  }
  $this.val(newVal.slice(0,-1))
})
```

Edit: See Joseph's answer above. His is shorter.

Comment: you could use keyup event to make it live.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But I like yours better - it's much shorter.

Comment: @Abraham- thanks. for this: 45,165,874 or 4,521,243 how is it?(normal number formatting)